NestJs Swagger mixed type with enum
I'm having small issues with NestJs Swagger ApiProperty Type generation.
Initially, everything was fine as I had ENUM. However, the 3rd party which I was pulling information from, added a few new values and suddenly my API started failing the validation.
To prevent this, I wanted to mix the ENUM with a string to make a wild card.
Sadly I can't make it work.
I tried with oneOf but once I do it this way the OpenApi is not generating anymore the ENUM :-(
export enum VehicleTypes {
  CAR = 'Car',
  BUS = 'Bus',
  TRUCK = 'Truck'
}

  @ApiProperty({
    oneOf: [
      { type: 'string' },
      {
        type: 'enum',
        enum: [...Object.values(VehicleTypes)],
      },
    ],
  })
  @Expose()
  vehicleType: VehicleTypes | string;

How I can make a Type which is expecting a value from the ENUM or eventually a string?

You can try this
@ApiProperty({
  required: true,
  example: VehicleTypes.CAR,
  enum: VehicleTypes,
 })
@IsEnum(VehicleTypes)
vehicleType: VehicleTypes | string;


This didn't work. The generated openapi schema is vehicleType: VehicleTypes, (it's not accepting a string outside of the enum values
